# shortening a nested `lapply(sapply())` call in R

Tags: r, function, dataframe, loops, tidyverse

My `lapply(sapply())` below works just fine. But I was wondering if there is a way to perhaps use just one call to a looping function instead of two like `lapply(sapply())` OR a way to make the code shorter?

```
hsb <- read.csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/rnorouzian/e/master/hsb.csv')
ch <- unique(hsb$sch.id)

ols <- lapply(1:2,function(j)sapply(ch,function(i)coef(lm(math~ses,data=hsb,subset=sch.id==i))[j]))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another way would be to use `purrr` library:

```
purrr::map_dfr(ch, ~ coef(lm(math ~ ses, data=hsb, subset=sch.id== .)))
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use a single `lapply` call instead of fitting the same model twice.

```
result <- do.call(rbind, lapply(ch,function(i)
                        coef(lm(math~ses,data=hsb,subset=sch.id==i))))
```

If you want `result` as a list use `asplit` :

```
asplit(result, 2)
```

Comment: That is because `pull` returns a vector and `map_df` expects a dataframe or list so they are incompatible. You can use `select` here since `select` returns a dataframe. `map_dfc(1:2,~select(coef(fit)$sch,.))` but why do you want to select one column ata a time and not do `coef(fit)$sch` ?

Comment: Ronak, I think [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64478086/reorganize-facet-wrap-panels-in-ggolt2) is right up your alley?